# In welcher Region wird "Angang" verwendet?

Tags: dialect, regional

Ich bin über das Wort "Angang" gestolpert und hielt es erst für eine falsche Schreibweise von "Anfang".

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Angang) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Angang) ist es aber ein eigenständiges Wort. Hier mal die Bedeutungsübersicht aus dem Duden:

> 1. (landschaftlich) Beginn, Anfang, Ansatzpunkt; Inangriffnahme
> 2. (Volkskunde) im Volksglauben zufälliges Zusammentreffen mit bestimmten Menschen oder Tieren, dem eine zukunftsbestimmende Bedeutung beigemessen wird

Es geht um den ersten Punkt. Kann mir jemand sagen, welche Landstriche die *landschaftliche* Verwendung umfasst?

---

Hier noch ein paar Beispiele aus dem DWDS-Korpus (Hervorhebung von mir) - wobei ich es für möglich halte, dass hier vertippte *Anfänge* dabei sind (z.B. beim zweiten Zitat):

> Man sollte in der Lage sein, nach einer Niederlage einen neuen **Angang** und dabei vielleicht einen anderen Weg auszuwählen.

*Die Welt, 25.09.2004*

> Wir machen von **Angang** an Druck, wollen in die nächste Runde.

*Bild, 05.08.1999*

> In ihrer Kombination hingegen sehe ich einen zusammenhängenderen, wirksameren und mehrversprechenden **Angang**, das nukleare Wettrüsten einzuschränken.

*Archiv der Gegenwart, 2001 [1978]*

> In diesem fundamentalen Angriff auf die „riesige Mißbildung“ der Industriegesellschaft schließen sich zumindest einige **Angänge** Batailles zusammen.

*Die Zeit, 21.11.1975, Nr. 48*

Comment: Ich stelle mal eine Vermutung an: Der Angang eines Motors ist ein Vorgang, bei dem ein Motor angeht. :-)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es geht mir nicht um die Bedeutung, sondern darum, WO das verwendet wird. Oh, oder war das ein Witz?

Comment: Ich habe Gebiete im Sinne von Sach- oder Fachgebieten fehlinterpretiert. Ich hätte aber auch durch das Wort _landschaftlich_ darauf kommen können, dass du Regionen meinst.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Darauf wäre ich nun wieder nicht gekommen :) Ich habe _Gebiete_ mal mit _Landstriche_ ersetzt, in der Hoffnung, dass es jetzt weniger irreführend ist.

Comment: Ich finde im Grimm praktisch dasselbe, allerdings dort nicht als *regional* bezeichnet. Ich denke, das sollte eher *archaisch* heißen. Wenn überhaupt noch, dann könnte *Angang* überall dort verwendet werden, wo man noch *geh' mir's an* sagt.

Comment: Die Zeitungskorpora des DWDS zeigen, dass es in überregionalen Zeitungen auch heute noch verwendet wird: https://www.dwds.de/r?q=Angang;corpus=public;format=full;p=1;sort=date_desc;limit=50. Dort sind auch viele Beispielsätze zu finden!

Comment: Reicht nicht für eine Antwort, deshalb nur als Kommentar: es gibt ein niederländisches Wort "aangang", das "Ansatz, Annäherung" bedeutet. Das führt zur Idee, dass es ein friesisches oder plattdeutsches Wort sein könnte. Man findet es auch in einem plattdeutschen Wörterbuch, dort bedeutet es aber auf hochdeutsch "Mühe". Irgendwie eine Sackgasse...

Comment: @Takkat Grade in den Pressekorpora vermute ich Einiges an OCR-Fehlern und misstraue denen ein bißchen. *Angang Mai* ist ziemlich sicher einer.

Comment: @tofro OCR-Fehler schließe ich bei den ganzen Online-Artikeln aus, zumal `g` und `f` gut unterscheidbar sind. Eher noch wäre ein Tippfehler der Redakteure anzunehmen (g liegt neben f), aber dann hätte ein häufiger Tippfehler zu einem Eintrag ins Wörterbuch geführt - gewagte These!

Comment: @Takkat Gar nicht. Der grosse Umfang eines Spellchecker-Wörterbuches ist oftmals mehr Fluch als Segen, wenn das Ding volkommen abstruse Wörter als "richtig" erkennt. In den Beispielen kommt "Angang April" und "Angang Mai" vor - das ist sehr sicher falsch.

Comment: @tofro: ich meinte mit Wörterbuch eigentlich nicht die redaktionellen Spellchecker sondern Duden, DWDS etc.

Comment: @Takkat Ich hatte auch für einen Moment gehofft, über die Herkunft der Zeitungen eine Idee zur regionalen Verteilung zu bekommen - aber hilfreich wäre wohl eher, die Herkunft der jeweiligen Redakteure/Journalisten zu kennen. Wir sind ja heute alle flexibel, mobil und ziehen gern der Arbeit hinterher :)

Comment: Das Argument für Irreführende spell-checkers gilt ebenso für den menschlichen Checker. Soll heißen: Die lautliche Nähe zu *Anfang* würde ein Missverständnis zwar nicht begünstigen, der Kontrast zu *Abgang* aber schon, obwohl dies sonst im Kontrast zu *Aufgang* steht. *eingangs* wäre zudem gleichbedeutend. Ein Zwischenschritt von dessen Wurzel via etwa Friesisch und zurück wäre denkbar? Falls Fränkisch im Spiel sein könnte vgl. En. *engage*? Zudem ist *angehen*, "anfangen, angreifen" gemein Deutsch. Vgl. ferner *entgegen*, *gegen [Zeit]*, "vor, zu", bspw. "gegen Mittag" ~ "Vormittag".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich nutze das Wort in der ersten Bedeutung tatsächlich recht häufig. Und zwar eher mit der Komponente "Mühe".
Beispiel: Ein Freund muss sich zu etwas durchringen, z.B. endlich eine Arbeit fertigmachen oder sich mit einem Konflikt auseinandersetzen. Dann sagt man: "Das ist ja auch ein Angang."
Komme aus NRW. Möglicherweise kommts aus dem Ruhrgebiet, vllt auch OWL. In Brandenburg ist die Verwendung übrigens gänzlich unbekannt.

Answer (score 3):

Aus dem Osten Österreichs kann ich nur berichten, dass es das Verb »angehen« mit der Bedeutung »beginnen« bzw. »bewerkstelligen« gibt, nicht aber das Substantiv »der Angang«.

Eher umgangssprachlich (z.B. Polier zu den Bauarbeitern):

> So, Leitln, auf! Die Pause is aus, gemmas wieda au.
>   So, Leute, steht auf! Die Pause ist zu Ende, **gehen** wir es wieder **an.** (Im Sinn von: *Beginnen wir wieder mit der Arbeit.*)

Standardsprachlich:

> Das scheint nicht einfach zu werden. Hast du einen Plan? Wie willst du das **angehen**? (Gleichbedeutend: Wie willst du das bewerkstelligen?)

Das Substantiv »der Angang« würde ich eher für ein fachsprachliches Vokabel halten (z.B. »Das Pferd zeigt im Angang eine Innenrotation des linken Vorderhufs, die beim fortwährenden Traben nicht mehr auftritt.« Oder »Das Gehäuse des Motors gerät im Angang mehrmals in heftige Resonanzvibrationen, die verschwinden, wenn der Motor die volle Drehzahl erreicht hat.«) Aber das sind Vermutungen.

Jedenfalls ist das Substantiv im Osten Österreichs nicht in Verwendung.

Comment: Guter Hinweis - an  _etwas angehen_ hatte ich gar nicht gedacht, aber das kenne ich auch.

Answer (score 0):

Die Beispiele halte ich für Druckfehler.
Am Auffälligsten ist "machen von Angang an Druck". Das ist Fußballersprache und da sagt niemand "Angang".
Auch in "sehe ich einen Angang" in Bezug auf das Wettrüsten sieht das ganz klar nach Druckfehler aus.

Die Beispiele passen auch gar nicht zu den Definitionen:

> 2. Volkskunde) im Volksglauben zufälliges Zusammentreffen mit bestimmten Menschen oder Tieren, dem eine zukunftsbestimmende Bedeutung beigemessen wird

In diesem Fall ist die Bedeutung sehr speziell und hat mit **Anfang** nichts zu tun.

> 1. (landschaftlich) Beginn, Anfang, Ansatzpunkt; Inangriffnahme

Von der Bedeutung her deuten alle Begriffe auf einen Rand von etwas hin, im Sinne von einem Übergang von einem zum anderen. Es ist in allen Fällen eher wörtlich zu nehmen als **der Anfang** der auch abstraktere Anfänge, wie z.B. einen Zeit bezogenen erlaubt.

Das Wort niedergeschrieben kam mir zunächst fremd vor. Der Ausdruck "gehen wir's an" dürfte aber überall recht geläufig sein und bezeichnet dann auch ein Schreiten zur Tat.
Bei einer Google such mit "im Angang" lassen sich aber einige verständliche Beisiele finden, z.B. "im Angang ausländischer Märkte" oder "Neufokussierung im Angang der Firmenkundensegmente" im unternehmerischen Sinn.
Auch im Bezug auf Wein scheint das gängig zu sein, was auch eine sinnvolle Ergänzung zum Abgang ist, von dem die meisten in der Beziehung gehört haben dürften.

Das dürfte also wohl kein regionales Phänomen sein, aber das Wort wird wohl sehr selten verwendet. Bei einer Suche nach **angang** auf Google werden zwar zunächst mehr als 700 000 Ergebnisse angezeigt, allerdings ist auf Seite 12 Schluss.

Comment: Es war auch ein Beispiel zur zweiten Bedeutung (Volkskunde) dabei. Das habe ich aber wieder raus genommen, da es hier nur um die erste Bedeutung gehen soll. Das Bsp. _von Angang an Druck_ halte ich auch für einen Druckfehler. Bei dem anderen bin ich nicht sicher. Unabhängig von der Qualität der Beispiele müssen Duden und DWDS ja irgendwie auf den Eintrag "landschaftlich" gekommen sein.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Es gibt auf Google schon recht viele Suchergebnisse z.B. mit *"von Angang an"*. Da könnte man schon denken, dass das Wort genau wie "Anfang" verwendet werden kann. Das wären dann schon viele Druckfehler oder eher Tippfehler. Allerdings ist so ein Tippfehler auch leicht zu machen und eher unauffällig. Leider ist schwer zu ermitteln ob das auch im Gesprochenen vorkommt.